# Why does the container size setting not working on ngOnInit?

Tags: angular, events, event-listener, ngoninit

I use this commands in order to set the size of the container:

```
ngOnInit() {

this.innerWidth = document.getElementById("Cont").clientWidth;
this.containerWidth = this.innerWidth;
console.log("init");
}

@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {

this.innerWidth = document.getElementById("Cont").clientWidth;
this.containerWidth = this.innerWidth;
}
```

When I load the page the container is larger than the window so that I have to scroll, after window resizing everything works as expected, no need to scroll anymore. Interesting is the fact that I see in the console he message "init" this should mean that the code is executed.

Why isn't the container sized onInit?

Thank you!

Comment: I may assume this is because the view is yet unstable. Do you render something after ngOnit?

Comment: Thank you for the reply Drag! I found the issue, there was indeed another command in the ngOnInit which interfed with the main command...

Comment: Nice to know issue is fixed! Good luck!

Comment: @Drag13 can you post answer so that OP can accept and upvote it? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294791/what-if-i-answer-a-question-in-a-comment

Comment: @Plochie actually I didn't give correct answer - just some suggestions to check

Answer (score 0):

I think you need manage this with CSS . But If you need to access dom element using selectors then please use ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook.

Try this .

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.innerWidth = document.getElementById("Cont").clientWidth;
     this.containerWidth = this.innerWidth;
  }
```

hope It helps !!